# What is the greatest number of yellow cards a team has got without a red card?

Tags: football, trivia, records

In the [Chelsea vs Spurs Premier League match on 2nd May 2016](http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/matchday/matches/2015-2016/epl.match-stats.html/chelsea-vs-spurs), Spurs received 9 yellow cards but without getting a red card. What's the greatest number of yellow cards a professional team has ever received without getting a red card? In theory, 14 would be possible if all 11 starting players and 3 substitutes got a yellow card.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I did say professional. I don't think U-15 counts as professional.

Comment: After your update, I've been bold and flipped this question round to the "greatest number" question. If you think this is *too* radical, please roll my edit back - but I do think it makes it a better SE question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious starter here is the Chelsea vs Spurs match mentioned in the question, where Spurs received 9 yellow cards.

Comment: Community wiki answer as it contains no content over that in the question. I'll delete this answer if/when an answer is posted with 10 or more yellow cards. I'd suggest any other examples of 9 yellow cards are edited into this answer.

Answer (score 3):

After my research , I found this :

[The Battle of Nuremberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Nuremberg_(2006_FIFA_World_Cup)) (also known as Massacre of Nuremberg) is the nickname of a football match played in the Last 16 of the 2006 FIFA World Cup between Portugal and the Netherlands at the Frankenstadion in Nuremberg on 25 June 2006. Russian referee Valentin Ivanov issued a FIFA World Cup record four red cards and 16 yellow cards, setting a new record for cards shown at any FIFA-administered international tournament.
And I think we don't have any match with 14 yellow cards for a team without a single red card.

Comment: Welcome to SE.Sport, do you know any source that confirm that this is a record for a single team?

Comment: Do you mean the record i told you that was for a match ( not for a single team )?